# Error 'NoneType' object is not callable from FuncAnimation inside a new class in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a new class to create plots with some pre-defined parameters of matplolib, so the process of creating a plot will be a little easier for what I am trying to create. So, basically I've got the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import style

style.use('ggplot')
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


class Plotting():
    def __init__(self, parent, file):

        self.parent = parent

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.figax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.parent)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.getData(file))

    def getData(self, file):

        self.file = file

        self.graphData = open(self.file).read()
        self.lines = self.graphData.split('\n')

        self.x1 = []
        self.y1 = []

        for line in self.lines:
            if len(line) > 1:
                self.x, self.y = line.split(',')
                self.x1.append(float(self.x))
                self.y1.append(float(self.y))

        self.figax1.clear()
        self.figax1.plot(self.x1, self.y1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
    frame1.pack()
    plot1 = Plotting(frame1, 'samplefile.txt')
    root.mainloop()
```

After running this, and having the sample file made of random numbers separated by ,
It create the Plot, but I've got several errors related to the FuncAnimation function.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 951, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\...\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1743, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\...\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1766, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *pass* the function to `FuncAnimation`, not call it. Furthermore, the updating function need to take the next value of `frames` as a first argument. This is [all explained in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation).

So at the minimum (although I cannot guarantee that there are no other errors in your code) you should write:

```
def __init__(...):
    (...)
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.getData, fargs=(file,))

def getData(self, frame, file):
    (...)
```